# A subspace of $H^1(0,\infty)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I am just wondering why a space like $H_0^1(0,\infty)=\{f\in H^1(0,\infty):f(0)=0\}$ is dense in $L^2(0,\infty)$ where $H^1$ is the Sobolev space?

Thanks in advance.

Math

Answer (score 1):

$C^{\infty }$ functions with compact support in $(0,\infty )$ are dense in $L^{2}(0,\infty )$. Such functions belong to $H^{1}_0(0,\infty )$.

Comment: A silly quyestion: Why is it that a function in $C^{\infty}$ with compact support must satisfy $f(0)=0$?

Comment: I meant compact support contained in $(0,\infty)$. By the way there is some problem with the statement itself. If your functions are defined on the open interval $(0,\infty )$ what does $f(0)=0$ mean?

Comment: Good point! I saw this in Schmudgen's book on unbounded self-adjoint operators on Page 17. So is this clear to see? I mean if I use $[0,\infty)$, then would it be simple to see that $f(0)=0$? Now, what if I use $H^1(\mathbb R)=\{f\in L^2(\mathbb R):f'\in L^2(\mathbb R)\}$. Would $X=\{f\in H^1(\mathbb R): f(0)=0\}$ still be dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: It would be. You can approximate $f\in X$ by smooth functions with compact  support contained in $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$. (These function actually vanish in a neighborhood of $0$).

Comment: Great! I will try to do that and see what I can get...